# Changing Data Frame display units in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, map-unit

Last week, in ArcMap 10, I went to View -> Data Frame Properties... -> General tab to change the data frame map display units from Decimal Degrees to Degrees Decimal Minutes. (the Map Units were still in Decimal Degrees, in fact it is greyed out and can't be changed)

Today, I wanted to change the Display units back to Decimal Degrees, but after I click Apply and OK, the map status bar still shows coordinates in Degrees Decimal Minutes as I move my cursor around the map. I went back to Data Frame Properties and the Display units have reverted back to Degrees Decimal Minutes!

Why is this happening, and what should I do?

Comment: are you re-projecting on the fly? even if one transformation is slightly out you will need to re-project the data sources.

Comment: Some of my layers were transformed from NAD27 into WGS 1984, while the Data Frame is defined as WGS 1984. Would this be the problem? If so, how do I correct this?

Comment: define your data sources and then use 'project' http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000007m000000.htm - look at 'usage' and geographic projections from NAD27

Comment: You might be hitting a bug. I seem to remember hearing about something similar. I would try setting the data frame coordinate system to a projected one, OK the dialog, then change it back to the geographic coordinate system.

Comment: I work for a state agency in Louisiana, and our GIS specialists say there is nothing wrong. I have told them and showed them time again that when you apply changes to the data frame properties - they do not register in ARC 10. perhaps there should be a recalculation and this task should be tempered - but wowee, I would think you should be able to freely change the units. This is unacceptable Jack!

Answer (score 3):

Check ArcMap Options > Data View and see if the option "Use these units instead of the data frame's Display units" is set.

Answer (score 2):

I just had exactly the same problem. It was using a data frame in wgs84 but unprojected. I tried projecting and unprojecting it and changing to decimal degrees but it didn't work.

My solution: For some reason choosing "kilometers" as the display units worked and then I could go back to decimal degrees. No Idea why but it seemed to fix the bug...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The solution I found was to go into Data Frame Properties click the Coordinate System tab and then double-click on the projection you are using to bring up the Projected Coordinate System Properties window and change the Linear Unit (it's a drop down near the middle) to feet or yards or whatever unit you want. It will still be greyed out when you go back, but the units will be whatever you set in the Projected Coordinate System Properties window.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to switch the display units to anything else and apply/ok, then you can pick decimal degrees and it will stick.

http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011883

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the folder AND any individual files within aren't "read only" I had this problem from copying a file over and forgot to change the read/write access. I saved changes to my map, changed the properties to the .mxd file and all linked tables and features (copies of them) to allow write access and reopened it and it worked fine. I hope this helps someone.